# BEP20 Tokens are not being swapped for BNB and sent to charity wallet

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to create a bep20-token where a percentage of the transaction volume is converted into BNB, and subsequently sent to a designated charity wallet to store the BNB for future donations. Another feature of this token is that a another part of the transaction is also swapped for BNB and locked together with the token in the liquidity pool. This last feature is working, however, the wallet I set up as the charity wallet is not receiving BNB. I have already set up a liquidity pool with the test tokens and minor amount of BNB thats how I learned its not doing what it was designed for. This token is a fork of YUMMY and the complete contract can be viewed here: https://bscscan.com/address/0x05f2df7b3d612a23fe12162a6c996447dce728a5#code

```
function sendBNBToCharity(uint256 amount) private { 
    swapTokensForEth(amount); 
    _charityWalletAddress.transfer(address(this).balance); 
}

function _setCharityWallet(address payable charityWalletAddress) external onlyOwner() {
    _charityWalletAddress = charityWalletAddress;
}

function swapAndLiquify(uint256 contractTokenBalance) private lockTheSwap {
    // split the contract balance into thirds
    uint256 halfOfLiquify = contractTokenBalance.div(4);
    uint256 otherHalfOfLiquify = contractTokenBalance.div(4);
    uint256 portionForFees = contractTokenBalance.sub(halfOfLiquify).sub(otherHalfOfLiquify);

    // capture the contract's current ETH balance.
    // this is so that we can capture exactly the amount of ETH that the
    // swap creates, and not make the liquidity event include any ETH that
    // has been manually sent to the contract
    uint256 initialBalance = address(this).balance;

    // swap tokens for ETH
    swapTokensForEth(halfOfLiquify); // <- this breaks the ETH -> HATE swap when swap+liquify is triggered
    swapTokensForEth(portionForFees);
    // how much ETH did we just swap into?
    uint256 newBalance = address(this).balance.sub(initialBalance);

    // add liquidity to uniswap
    addLiquidity(otherHalfOfLiquify, newBalance);
    sendBNBToCharity(portionForFees);
    
    emit SwapAndLiquify(halfOfLiquify, newBalance, otherHalfOfLiquify);
}

function swapTokensForEth(uint256 tokenAmount) private {
    // generate the uniswap pair path of token -> weth
    address[] memory path = new address[](2);
    path[0] = address(this);
    path[1] = uniswapV2Router.WETH();

    _approve(address(this), address(uniswapV2Router), tokenAmount);

    // make the swap
    uniswapV2Router.swapExactTokensForETHSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
        tokenAmount,
        0, // accept any amount of ETH
        path,
        address(this),
        block.timestamp
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your `swapTokensForEth` function is swapping to WETH, not to ETH. Wrapped ETH is a coin that holds ETH and makes it act like an ERC20 token, so that it can be used on Uniswap and other place.

To get ETH out of your WETH, you'll need call `WETH.withdraw(amount)`, which will convert your WETH back to ETH.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! I learned on another forum that the problem lies in the router address which is the old address (V1 for pancakeswap) and I used the V2 liquidity pool.

Comment: Did you figure this out?